# Not able to get max amount and update the status in Apex

Tags: apex, after-trigger, code, aggregateresult

i have requirement where i need to get all orders from account and need to check max amount from that order
and need to update the status of order to InProgress.

[image]

then from **account1 ==>order4** needs to be updated with status (InProgress) and **Account2==>order2**

I tried with below code but stuck ,i dont want to use aggregate

```
public class OrderAmountStatusChange {

    public static void updateOrderStatus(list<account> accList) {
        set<id> accIds = new set<id>();
        for(account acc:accList) {
            accIds.add(acc.id);
        }
        List<order> orderList = new list<order>([select status,TotalAmount from order where id in:accIds]);
        map<id,order> orderMap = new map<id,order>();
        for(order ord:orderList) {
            orderMap.put(ord.accountid,ord);
        }
         map<id,list<integer>> orderUpdateOnAmount = map<id,list<integer>> ();
        for(account acc:accList) {
            for(order ord:ordermap.values()){
                integer amount=0;
                if(ord.AccountId == acc.id) {
                        orderUpdateOnAmount.put(ord.id,orderUpdateOnAmount)                        
                    }

                }  

            } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do explain why you don't want to use an aggregate query here. They exist for this sort of logic.

Comment: requirement is like that  only.once i received answer why not aggregste. I will explain here as well.thanks

Comment: please let me know any way without using an aggregate and inner query..any way to do by calculations?

Comment: This is software - there is pretty much always a way. But by executing this sort of logic in the database layer you are less likely to run into governor limits, are likely to get quicker response, and also end up with less code which generally means less bugs. So challenge this requirement. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_whys.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner query and then pick the order having highest amount:

```
List<account> accs = [Select Name, (select status,TotalAmount from orders order by TotalAmount desc limit 1) FROM Account where Id IN: accIds];
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
for(account a: accs){
   for(Order o : a.orders){
       o.Status = 'Pending';
       orders.add(o);
   }
}
if(orders.isEmpty() == false) update orders;
```

After that you can traverse and work as per your requirement.

Comment: can you provide sample code for traversing as well as i am bit confused

Comment: do you mean to say this kind of traversingfor(account acc:accs) {
            for(order ord:acc.orders) {
                ord.Status ='Pending';
                
            } 
        }

Comment: Let me update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use an aggregate query. It's the exact use case for it, and it's the most efficient solution in terms of CPU time and length of code.